# handle datatables data in asp.net handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables

i am working on a project using asp.net, C#, Html5, Javascript and other languages and can't resolve this problem:

```
$('#getdata').click(function (e) {
            var data = oTable.fnGetData();
            //alert(data[0][1]);

            $.ajax({
                url: "HandlerSaveNutrition.ashx?P=" + proid,
                data: {data: data},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });

        });
```

here i get the data of the datatables and sendit to asp handler, but i can't handle the object send it to insert the data in sql database.
any help please.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't handle the object"?  The POST request should have a serialized object of some sort, identified by the key `data`.  In your server-side code, what do you do with that object?  You say you're having trouble interacting with the database, where is your code for doing that?  As a side note, calling everything "data" will likely lead to confusion.  I would recommend using more descriptive variable names that differ between separate contexts (such as the function parameter in the `success` callback).

Comment: forget the success function. the data is 2 dimension array object, how can i convert it to array object in c# to extract the values and insert it to database?

Comment: If it's JSON then you can probably use the Newtonsoft JSON library (which is included in just about every Visual Studio project template these days, but is also readily available on NuGet if you don't have it yet) to deserialize it.  If it's a 2-dimensional array then a `string[][]` might work, or perhaps a `List<List<string>>`?  I'd recommend a more structured object, of course.  Something like a `List<SomeCustomObject>` where `SomeCustomObject` represents a record in the client-side table.  Though I suppose just deserializing it to `dynamic` would likely work as well.